# How to get docker images created from docker-in-docker

Tags: docker

I am using `docker:dind` to create some images. And it works fine. When I execute into the `docker:dind` container and do a `docker images` or `docker ps` I can see the images and containers respectively.

But without always executing into the `docker:dind` container, how can I list the images and container from outside?

(I know this is possible as once I read an article about this. But I can't seem to find that good article. )

Answer (score 0):

## Docker socket

Docker uses the unix(in the most cases) socket to communicate with its Daemon, so you need you need to mount this socket file into the running container.

Docker socket is usually in the `/var/run/docker.sock`

Docker in docker may be hard if docker is running on VM.

---

## Docker in docker

Let's do some simple example.

#### 1. Pull docker image

```
$ docker pull docker:latest
```

#### 2. Start docker in dockder

First, you need to locate your unix socket and mount it into docker container with the `-v` flag. Docker will exec when it will finish executing passed command. So let's execute `sleep` for `1 hour`

```
$ docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -d docker:latest sleep 3600
52201aaa3e6ebaaafab0a7323fd621f9f41765bad6363bf4eae43bf06c5825ee
```

#### 3. Let's shell into started container

We can use the `exec` command with `-ti` flags

```
$ docker exec -ti 52201aaa3e6ebaaafab0a7323fd621f9f41765bad6363bf4eae43bf06c5825ee sh
/ #
```

#### 4. Try to start MySQL from the docker container

```
/ # docker run -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true  mysql:5.7

2021-01-28 20:17:24+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.32-1debian10 started.
2021-01-28 20:17:24+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2021-01-28 20:17:24+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.32-1debian10 started.
2021-01-28 20:17:24+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
...
...
...

2021-01-28T20:17:33.146086Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2021-01-28T20:17:33.147569Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2021-01-28T20:17:33.156949Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2021-01-28T20:17:33.157405Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.32'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

#### 5. Verify it is working

Let's open another terminal tab on the host and verify if started container is working

```
$ docker ps | grep mysql:5.7
bc90ce617ee4        mysql:5.7              "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   3306/tcp, 33060/tcp                   trusting_neumann
```

That's everything. You are running Docker in Docker.

---

## Docker in another host

You can also start docker container on your computer and you can do control Docker on another machine. The requirement is, that docker on remote machine has socket listening on TCP socket, and you are allowed to communicate with that endpoint. This is common way to control docker when you use docker in the VM, you can be on your local laptop and you can do development on some server in the server room.

To read more, you can see how to setup docker daemon listening on the TCP socket and how to connect to the remote socket in [the official docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/)